# Trying to remove commas causes params to be empty in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to remove commas from a field before it hits my database (it cuts everything off after the comma).  I've tried using a before callback with this method :

```
def remove_comma_from_total_price
 self.total_price = self.total_price.to_s.gsub(/,/,'')
end
```

and also tried another solution I found on SO

```
def total_price=(num)
  num.gsub!(/,/,'') if num.is_a?(String)
  self[:total_price] = num.to_i
end
```

This seems the work in the console, but when I'm submitting the post request, the params being submitted are
UPDATED with the parameters being sent:

```
"proposal"=>{"job_id"=>"6", "work_order_id"=>"10", "brand_id"=>"2", "total_price"=>""}
```

View:

```
<div class="highlight">
  <%= f.input :total_price, label: "Total Price:", wrapper_html: {class: "dollars"} %>
</div>
```

I'm using MySQL database with the type DECIMAL on Rails 4.1.5.

Please let me know if you'd like the see the controllers or anything else.

Comment: You should be doing parameter cleanup in your controller, not the model. What's an example of a parameter set with these problematic commas?

Comment: `":total_price"` looks weird. How do you send it?

Comment: I updated the post with the full params being sent and posted the part of the form in the view

Comment: **SOLVED**  the issue was simple form was had the input field set to number and was automatically converting anything with a comma to 0.0 before being sent. The total_price=(num) method functions properly and removes the comma once the correct info gets sent.